# Windows command promt calculations error

Tags: command-line, windows-8

I'm using windows 8 and want to write bat file to log time how long task is running. So I write this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

SET STARTTIME=%TIME%

.....do sth. smart.....

SET ENDTIME=%TIME%
SET /A DURATION=%ENDTIME%-%STARTTIME%
SET /A DURATIONH=%DURATION%/360000
SET /A DURATIONM=(%DURATION%-%DURATIONH%*360000)/6000
SET /A DURATIONS=(%DURATION%-%DURATIONH%*360000-%DURATIONM%*6000)/100
SET /A DURATIONHS=(%DURATION%-%DURATIONH%*360000-%DURATIONM%*6000-%DURATIONS%*100)
if %DURATIONH% LSS 10 SET DURATIONH=0%DURATIONH%
if %DURATIONM% LSS 10 SET DURATIONM=0%DURATIONM%
if %DURATIONS% LSS 10 SET DURATIONS=0%DURATIONS%
if %DURATIONHS% LSS 10 SET DURATIONHS=0%DURATIONHS%
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo task start time : %STARTTIME%
echo task end time : %ENDTIME%
echo task end in time : %DURATIONH%:%DURATIONM%:%DURATIONS%,%DURATIONHS%
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

endlocal

C:
PAUSE
```

I run it and it passed but log time is (f.e.):

```
task start time 14:35:36,24
task end time 14:39:43,55
task end in time : 00:00:00,14
```

and also show error missing operator on this :

```
SET /A DURATION=%ENDTIME%-%STARTTIME%
```

Could you help me? I'm searching about that issue but I couldn't find nothing to mached witch my issue

Thanks for help

Comment: This is explained in the documentation when you type `set /?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to convert your timestrings to seconds - and it's not that easy.

Fortunately, since you're using a 24-hour clock - which makes it easier, but the programmer who wrote the maths enhancements decided for some bizarre reason to define a string with a leading zero as OCTAL so '08' or '09' in a substring will generate an error as 08/09 are not valid octal numbers...

SO - the standard method of getting over that is to string a '1' in front of the string and then subtract 100.

Next complication is that you are using `,` as a decimal separator - and this compounds the problem that we can only use INTEGER mathematics...

Fortunately, seen such things before. The solution is **UGLY+** but it works.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: simply setting the start and end time to your posted values...
SET starttime=14:35:36,24
SET endtime=14:39:43,55
:: Here are some other value-pairs of interest (1) - elapsed = 8399,04
:: SET starttime=14:35:36,24
:: SET endtime=14:35:35,28
:: Here are some other value-pairs of interest (2) - elapsed = 0,04
:: SET starttime=14:35:36,24
:: SET endtime=14:35:36,28
:: Here are some other value-pairs of interest (3) - elapsed = 0,31
:: SET starttime=14:35:36,24
:: SET endtime=14:35:36,55
:: Here are some other value-pairs of interest (4) - elapsed = 7,31
:: SET starttime=14:35:36,24
:: SET endtime=14:35:43,55
CALL :CONVERT startsecs "%starttime%"
CALL :CONVERT endsecs "%endtime%"
ECHO SET /a elapsed=%endsecs% - %startsecs%
SET /a elapsed=endsecs - startsecs
IF %elapsed% lss 0 SET /a elapsed=%elapsed% + (24*360000)
IF %elapsed% lss 100 (IF %elapsed% lss 10 (SET elapsed=00%elapsed%) ELSE (SET elapsed=0%elapsed%))
ECHO elapsed TIME : %elapsed:~0,-2%,%elapsed:~-2%
::
GOTO :eof
en
:CONVERT
SET hundredths=%~2
SET /a %1=((((((1%hundredths:~0,2%) * 60) + 1%hundredths:~3,2%) * 60) + 1%hundredths:~6,2%) * 100) + 1%hundredths:~9,2% - 36610100
SET /a hundredths=((((((1%hundredths:~0,2% - 100) * 60) + 1%hundredths:~3,2% - 100) * 60) + 1%hundredths:~6,2% - 100) * 100) + 1%hundredths:~9,2% - 100
ECHO %2 %hundredths%
GOTO :eof
```

I've included a few value-pairs for ease of testing, together with a comment about the elapsed time using your convention.

First cab off the rank is to deal with the comma. Comma is a default separator, so the easy way is to quote the time parameter being passed to the `:convert` routine. The first parameter is the name of the variable into which to place the result of the calculation.

Within the routine, the variable `hundredths` is set to the second parameter (the quoted time-string) and the quotes removed (`%~2`)

Then the calculation-proper is done. Skipping the `SET /a %1=...` line for the moment, the required calculation is shown in the `set hundredths=` line that follows. String each substring of the supplied time with a leading `1`, subtract 100 and multiply by 60, 60, 100 in turn to calculate hundredths-of-seconds-since-midnight. The result of this calculation is simply then displayed.

I included the full calculation as it is the ancestor of the simplified calculation assigned to `%1`. The magic figure 36610100 is simply the sum of the constants added to the calculation by the octal-protection mantra.

The full version of the calculation could be commented-out as it plays no part in the conversion mechanism. The `ECHO` of the result is best deleted - just there to show results during an evaluation.

Once the start and end times are converted to hundredths-since-midnight, subtract to get the elapsed time. If the result is less than 100, decide on how many leading zeroes to add, and display the result "as if from a PIC 9'sV99"

Comment: Thank you that works :). Also thank you for explanation it's very helpful for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't subtract time strings, you need to convert `%STARTTIME%` and `%ENDTIME%` to seconds first, and then compute `%DURATION%`. Just to give you a hint:

```
set STARTTIME=%TIME%
set /A STARTTIME=%STARTTIME:~0,2%*3600+%STARTTIME:~3,2%*60+%STARTTIME:~6,2%
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it counts for 24h (also 1x over midnight):

```
@echo off&setlocal
for /f "tokens=1-3delims=:," %%a in ("%time%") do (
    set /a "shr=(1%%a)-100"
    set /a "smin=(1%%b)-100"
    set /a "ssec=(1%%c)-100"
)
set /a startsec=%shr%*3600+%smin%*60+%ssec%
echo start at sec: %startsec%

ping -n 20 localhost >nul &rem .....do sth. smart.....

for /f "tokens=1-3delims=:," %%a in ("%time%") do (
    set /a "ehr=(1%%a)-100"
    set /a "emin=(1%%b)-100"
    set /a "esec=(1%%c)-100"
)
set /a endsec=%ehr%*3600+%emin%*60+%esec%
echo stop  at sec: %endsec%
if %startsec% leq %endsec% (set /a diffsec=%endsec%-%startsec%) else set /a diffsec=%endsec%+86400-%startsec%
echo running %diffsec% second(s^)
set /a ehr=(%diffsec%/3600)
set /a emin=(%diffsec%-(%ehr%*3600))/60
set /a esec=(%diffsec%-(%ehr%*3600)-(%emin%*60))
echo running for %ehr%h %emin%min %esec%sec
```

Comment: Hi, I try your code but it doesn't work. I'll have problem Unbalanced parenthesis.
Missing operand.
start at sec:
Unbalanced parenthesis.
Missing operand.
stop  at sec:
(set was unexpected at this time.